# Using sed steam editor to replace a specific string of regular and special characters

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

Using the command line utility `sed` stream editor, how can I replace the following string of regular and special characters **&#39;** with a single quote **'**

For example, I want to replace **&#39;** with a single quote **'** from the below sentences:

FROM:

```
Nicholas Latifi: \&#39;We didn\&#39;t get through all the laps we wanted to\&#39; in Mexico City Friday practice
Despite \&#39;strong race pace\&#39; in FP1, gearbox issues hampered George Russell\&#39;s Mexican GP Friday practice
```

TO:

```
Nicholas Latifi: 'We didn't get through all the laps we wanted to' in Mexico City Friday practice
Despite 'strong race pace' in FP1, gearbox issues hampered George Russell's Mexican GP Friday practice
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, how does it not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you also want to strip away the semicolon, too: Hence:

```
sed -e "s/&#39;/'/g" file > file.new
```

or without output redirection, modifying in-place:

```
sed -ie "s/&#39;/'/g" file
```

The 'g' modifier signals that a global substitution (i.e. all occurrences in each line) is desired.

If you have a string to filter this will look like:

```
echo "hello&#39;world"|sed -e "s/&#39;/'/g"
hello'world
```